# How handle frequency data to make it comparable between different sized samples?

Tags: binomial-distribution, frequency

I have gathered data on presence / absence of objects at 4 different locations from a number of studies (12 to be exact).
I am interested in knowing how frequently each of these objects are recorded as present and compare the rates for each object between locations.

My crux is that I have a lot of variation in sample sizes, both between locations and between objects within locations. That is, most of the studies I have only sampled one or two of these locations, and some explicitly lack data on certain objects.

The differences in sample size between objects within locations is less of an issue, since calculating relative frequency-of-presence will allow for direct comparison between objects.

But how should I treat my data to allow comparison between locations as well?

Comment: Frequency, meaning a count, is not "normalised" in any sense. If I understand this correctly you will need to look at proportions or relative frequencies, but keep track of sample size. The old joke 1/3 did this, 1/3 did that and the other person wouldn't answer shows that sample size (here 3) is part of the information.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your are right in how you interpret the question. I appear to have mixed up the terminology a bit. I have edited my post a bit based on your comment. Hope that makes things clearer.

Comment: How many different kinds of objects? You have nested data, so some kind of mixed model logistic regression